# Is it natural to say that a problem is minuscule?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, I want to say that ordinary people are not wary of the importance of the increasing number of endangered species. Is it true to use the adjective "minuscule" in this case?

> To ordinary people, the increasing number of endangered species might
> seem minuscule and peculiar to animals, but scientists believe that
> loss of animal divergence will also threaten humans' long-term
> survival.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that a problem is minuscule, but you don't!  You say the number of species is minuscule. You either need to include the word "problem" or "issue" or change the word to "unimportant" or similar.